# WPF: Need a nearly "invisible" TabControl. What do I need to override?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

For my application, I need a `TabControl` which will host 2 DataGrids. The control must be as unobtrusive as possible: only the tabs should be seen.

I am told that the solution is somewhere here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137.aspx

I guess that I will have to change some value(s) to zero (maybe negative?)

Can you folks provide details?

TIA

Comment: It doesn't make sense.  If you want only the tabs to be seen, why populate them with data grids?  Can you clarify?

Comment: Tab Controls have shadows and borders. My 2 DataGrids are inside a container inside a container inside a container and are too busy. Every pixel counts. There is **another**, third DataGrid to the left of the tabbed ones and I want the non-tabbed DataGrid to look exactly (border and shadow-wise) like the tabbed DataGrids.

Comment: Conceptually, what I need is a couple button: when one is depressed the other is not, and DataGrids magically appear and disappear upon clicking the "buttons".

Comment: Good!  That's a WPF toggle button whose state is bound to the visibility property of the data grids.  All the rest is styling on the grids.  Everything so far can be done in Xaml.  You may want to edit your question to ask specifics on toggle buttons, etc.

Comment: Just remove the `Margin` and `Padding` properties from the default `TabControl` template found in the link you posted.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's much easier to use a `RadioButton` than a `TabControl`

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <RadioButton Name="tab1" Content="Tab 1" />
    <RadioButton Name="tab2" Content="Tab 2" />
</StackPanel>
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Visibility>
        <Binding ElementName="tab1" Path="IsChecked">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <BooleanToVisibilityConverter />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </DataGrid.Visibility>
</DataGrid>
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Visibility>
        <Binding ElementName="tab2" Path="IsChecked">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <BooleanToVisibilityConverter />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </DataGrid.Visibility>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I disagree with this answer. a `TabControl` dynamically creates / destroys the Visual Tree with every TabItem change. your approach does not do that

Comment: @HighCore Asker never said he needed that functionality

Comment: I may have to add more DataGrids later, and I like the 3-sided tabs, which will be at the bottom, btw. I need the control of the visual trees as well. I definitely want a tab control (with zero-width "canvas" border).

Comment: @Travis You can always style a radiobutton to look like a tab. And if you have large datagrids, loading them into the visual tree every time you change a tab will be slow. There's nothing wrong with this answer unless we get into a whole separate question of memory consumption.